# css divs text overlap issue

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I have 4 divs as you see on the picture.

[image]

They are positioned this way :

```
<style>
div1{ 
    max-width:250px;
    min-width:240px;
    position:absolute;
    right:6px;
    top:6px;
    float:left;
}
div2{
max-width:2248px;
position:absolute;
height:35px;
left:254px;
margin-right:20px;
min-width:275px;}

div3{
max-width:250px;
min-width:240px;
position:absolute;
right:6px;
top:6px;
float:right;}

div4{
position:fixed;
top:1px;
right:400px;
margin-left:260px;}
</style>
```

The issue I am having is that div4 gets its content from the database, if there is more text it goes UNDER div2. and makes it impossible to read.
looking for a way to make so that if there is more text (or if you resize the browser) as text on div4 wraps, div2 is pushed down (if the width is narrowed) or pushed up (if the browser width is made wider)
any ideas?

Comment: Do you want divs 1 & 3 to remain at the same height while 2 resizes?

Comment: @BG_Insight yes pls. at Chris : pic is on top

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have elements that react to other elements, then you need to use a layout method that keeps your elements in the flow. `position:absolute;` is like superglue, it's best used sparingly and only when nothing else sticks...

The other approach is to programmatically adjust the positioning during resize, but this is not recommended.

Comment: yeah I tried to programmatically adjust the positioning it turned out into a big mess caused other positioning issues.